# Unexpected boolean value in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, boolean

I know for a fact that the content of inputbox that I'm submitting exists in table1, yet this query:

```
$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name=$_POST[inputbox]");

var_dump($check);
```

is giving me a bool(false)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **You are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection.** Please learn about using parametrized queries, preferably with the PDO module, to protect your web app.   http://bobby-tables.com/php has examples to get you started.

Comment: @AndyLester Thanks for the concern. This will be used only by me locally. It won't be going on the interwebs.

Comment: It's probably not a bad idea to build good habits early, though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe try:

```
$check = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE name='".$_POST[inputbox]."'");
```

Comment: +1 but don't forget about [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php). However I prefer PDO :)

Comment: Cool, doing that gave me a different result which means it's working. Now how do I make use of the result which shows as: object(mysqli_result)#2 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(6)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}

Comment: @phptinkerer use mysqli_fetch_array to assign the result to an array

Answer (score 0):

A general advice, if you want to know whats going wrong, use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.error.php):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, '......');
if(!$result) {
    die(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not getting an error, just an unexpected result.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the $con var is true because if the connection failed you will always get bool(false).

If it is ok try to update the query by name LIKE '" . $_POST[inputbox] . "';